# Transactional updates to Sybase from Dblib to DBI

Tags: perl, sybase, dbi

I have a perl code currently, that connects to Sybase via Sybase::DBlib and does the following

```
$dbh->sql('Begin tran');
$query= <some delete query>
$dbh->sql($query)
in a loop{
    do insert query
}
COMPLETE:
$dbh->sql('commit tran');
```

I am porting the above code to start using DBI instead, but I am not sure how to work with transactions. How can I emulate the above using DBI. And what does `COMPLETE` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes.**

Look at [TRANSACTIONS in the DBI docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Transactions). It gives this code example.

> ```
> $dbh->{AutoCommit} = 0;  # enable transactions, if possible
> $dbh->{RaiseError} = 1;
> eval {
>     foo(...)        # do lots of work here
>     bar(...)        # including inserts
>     baz(...)        # and updates
>     $dbh->commit;   # commit the changes if we get this far
> };
> if ($@) {
>     warn "Transaction aborted because $@";
>     # now rollback to undo the incomplete changes
>     # but do it in an eval{} as it may also fail
>     eval { $dbh->rollback };
>     # add other application on-error-clean-up code here
> }
> ```

For your specific use-case, you could do:

```
$dbh->{AutoCommit} = 0;
$dbh->{RaiseError} = 1;
eval {
    $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM stuff");
    $dbh->execute;
    $dbh->commit;
};
if ($@) {
    warn "Transaction aborted because $@";
    eval { $dbh->rollback };
}
```

The most important part is that you need to **turn [`AutoCommit`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#AutoCommit) off yourself** before you start with your transaction. That works by just changing the internals of the `$dbh`.

Note that you can also use [Try::Tiny](http://p3rl.org/Try::Tiny) instead of the `eval` block, which looks a bit nicer.

If you want to turn auto-committing back on so there are no transactions any more, just set `$dbh->{AutoCommit} = 1`.

---

You can also use [`begin_work`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#begin_work) and [`commit`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#commit) and leave [`$dbh->{AutoCommit}`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#AutoCommit) at `1`, so you don't have to mess with it.

```
use Try::Tiny;

try {
    $dbh->begin_work;
    $dbh->do( ... );
    $dbh->commit;
catch {
    warn "Transactino aborted because $_";
    try { $dbh->rollback };
};
```

Comment: and how do i turn it back on?

Comment: just confirming. Thanks. :)

Comment: also, in using DBlib, the code above does not really do a rollback, then what is the use of COMPLETE:commit tran anyway? 
Or is rollback handled differently in dblib?

Comment: @Kraken I don't know, sorry. I've never used Sybase.

Comment: I can use eval {} with begin_work right? Or do I HAVE to use try/catch?

Comment: @Kraken you can use `eval {}` of course. I just like to promote modern Perl in my answers. ;)